# symfony2 - how override controller __construct

Tags: symfony, controller, php

I am having some trouble with Symfony2. Namely in how to use the `__construct()` function. the Official Documentation is shockingly bad!

I want to be able to use the following:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
}
```

How ever I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot call constructor in /Sites/src/DEMO/DemoBundle/Controller/Frontend/HomeController.php on line 11
```

Line 11 is `parent::__construct();`. I removed it and got the following, new error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /Sites/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php on line 242
```

I think I might need to set up the `ContainerInterface` DIC, but I have no idea how to do this (I tried and failed, miserably)

Any ideas folks?

Comment: You should better use 4 spaces to highlight your code instead of using `>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually quite a common misconception for new S2 developers.  As @KingCrunch says, the S2 controller has no construct and thus your approach will fail.  Take a look at the source code: namespace Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller and you will see that the Controller extends component ContainerAware which has one method called setContainer.  If you really wanted to, you could override this method and do what you want.

However, there is an event system specifically designed for these sorts of things i.e. executing certain methods before the action method gets kicked off.  Might want to search a bit for other questions on this topic.

The S2.1 controller now has a getUser() method.  I'd suggest adding it to your base controller class and not worrying about it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know, which class you extended, but the symfony controller doesn't have a constructor. Thus it's exactly, like the message suggest

```
Fatal error: Cannot call constructor in
/Sites/src/DEMO/DemoBundle/Controller/Frontend/HomeController.php on line 11

Line 11 is "parent::__construct();"
```

It cannot call the constructor, because *it doesn't exists*.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
}
```

Worth to note, that you don't even need to extend any class, or implement any interface. A symfony2-controller can be a completely independent standalone class.

> the Official Documentation is shockingly bad!

Where does the documentation suggest to call the parents constructor ;)